# iOS sdk custom navigation bar type top bar in iphone app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

i'm woking on my first iphone app. the app uses a tab bar template, the current iteration of the app doesn't use a navigation controller, but now i need someway of presenting an action sheet in one of the views to allow users to save images to the photos app or e-mail the same image and even more importantly for the app let them use air print to print the image they are viewing. for the look and feel to stay consistent i need something like a system navigation bar; something that looks like one, that would allow me to place a button inside it so that then users could tap that to get the action sheet.

what is the best way of doing that? would this top bar have to be like any other view in the hierarchy? can i place any type of button inside any view? a button icon like the system one that the action one? (in the human interface guidelines - system buttons/icons).
many apps implement this type of thing but like i said it's my first one.

thanks in advance

Comment: You should **really** read UIKit's documentation. You can find there very simple and important objects, including UIToolbar and UINavigationBar

Comment: i hadn't read the documentation for uitoolbar; i'm doing that now. i do really read the documentation and if you read the question carefully it talks about a user interface element that only looks like  a navigation controller, but without any of the functionalities of that template that you get for free or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UIToolbar`. It looks and acts pretty similar to a `UINavigationBar`. You can place it anywhere as it is just a subclass of `UIView`.

Comment: Just checked and saw your answer. thanks for taking the time to answer my question, i will go and check the documentation for uitoolbar right now.

Comment: i have checked the documentation; the uitoolbar class reference for a start and the human interface guidelines. the (hig) state categorically that as an interface element a uitoolbar always appears at the bottom of a screen/view, on ipad they can appear at the top. in my specific case as the question says i need the bar at the top of the screen/view.

Comment: You can still place it anywhere you want, it will look the same as a `UINavigationBar`. You could create a `UINavigationController` or a `UINavigationBar`, but it would really be much easier to just use a `UIToolbar`.